# How do I extract only the first rows of grouped items in R?

Tags: r, group-by, subset, data-manipulation

I have a listing of New York Mets baseball players from the `Lahman` database in alphabetical order. For each player are the years he played in ascending order. I need to extract for each player just the data for the first year he played and put all the first rows into a new data frame.

On my Mac in `RStudio` I have gotten to the point where the data I need is grouped and ordered. Here is a sample.

```
playerID,yearID,G,AB,R,H
aceveju01,1997,25,6,0,0
acostma01,2010,41,0,0,0
acostma01,2011,44,0,0,0
acostma01,2012,45,0,0,0
adkinjo01,2007,1,0,0,0
agbaybe01,1998,11,15,1,2
agbaybe01,1999,101,276,42,79
agbaybe01,2000,119,350,59,101
agbaybe01,2001,91,296,28,82
ageeto01,1968,132,368,30,80
ageeto01,1969,149,565,97,153
ageeto01,1970,153,636,107,182
ageeto01,1971,113,425,58,121
ageeto01,1972,114,422,52,96
aguilch01,2008,8,12,0,2
```

For testing purposes, I started with this code instead of with `piping`. That is as far as I was able to advance.

```
Lahman_batting18 <- read.csv('Batting-copy.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Lahman_batting18s <- select(Lahman_batting18,playerID:SO)
Lahman_batting18f <- filter(Lahman_batting18s,teamID == 'NYN')
Lahman_batting18fa <- arrange(Lahman_batting18f, playerID, yearID)
```

Desired output:

```
playerID,yearID,G,AB,R,H
aceveju01,1997,25,6,0,0
acostma01,2010,41,0,0,0
adkinjo01,2007,1,0,0,0
agbaybe01,1998,11,15,1,2
ageeto01,1968,132,368,30,80
aguilch01,2008,8,12,0,2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `d[ave(1:NROW(d), d$playerID, FUN = seq_along) == 1,]`

Comment: @d.b. How does your code work?

Comment: Hello [metsfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157636/metsfan), would you please accept the answer (tick mark beside the answer...), if it's a solution to your question? it then shows that the problem is solved.

Comment: `Lahman_batting18 %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  slice(1L)
`

Comment: @RonakShah What is the difference between using slice(1L) and slice(1)?

Comment: @Metsfan both are of different `class`. `1L` is integer and `1` is numeric. Check `class(1L)` and `class(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

[d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128934/d-b) used base `r`, while I'm more fond of `dplyr` & `pipe`s.

```
Lahman_batting18 %>% group_by(playerID) %>% arrange(playerID, yearID) %>% 
filter(yearID == min(yearID))
```

Filtering only the year where it's minimum. I hope this is what you want? Output that I get using your exemplary data:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   playerID [6]
  playerID  yearID     G    AB     R     H
  <fct>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 aceveju01   1997    25     6     0     0
2 acostma01   2010    41     0     0     0
3 adkinjo01   2007     1     0     0     0
4 agbaybe01   1998    11    15     1     2
5 ageeto01    1968   132   368    30    80
6 aguilch01   2008     8    12     0     2
```

Comment: In your output, the playerID is not in alphabetical order which is how I would prefer it to be. Yours is ordered by yearID.

Comment: Oh sorry, corrected it. Now the output is exact for the code I mentioned...

Comment: @Ronak Shah Today, I checked the total number of first rows using these 2 solutions: (1) Season1_all <- Lahman_batting18 %>% group_by(playerID) %>% arrange(playerID, yearID) %>% filter(yearID == min(yearID)) (2) Season1_all2 <- Lahman_batting18 %>% group_by(playerID) %>% slice(1) I expected the total number of rows in the  solutions to be the same, but they are not. Solution 1 has 19,999 rows; whereas, Solution 2 has 19,428 rows. Further, when I ran "distinct(Lahman_batting18, playerID)" I also got 19,428 rows. Why am I getting the different numbers? Which solution is giving correct total?